# Health check - web

Tags: docker, http, docker-compose

Currently I am trying to check if a webservice running inside a docker container is healthy and if its HTTP status code is 200.

But dockers built in healthcheck only checks for exit codes.

I am running this command via terminal:

```
curl -o /dev/null -s -w "%{http_code}\n" http://localhost:8080/api/health
```

And check if the returned status code is 200.
How can I embed this one inside dockers healthcheck?

Answer (score 1):

You can work with the fact that `HEALTHCHECK` only checks the exit code values of a command as follows:

1. Use the `-w` and `-s` options in `curl` to only output the http status code of the api request
2. Use bash test expressions to check the status code

The `HEALTHCHECK` in your Dockerfile might look like this:

```
HEALTHCHECK --interval=20s --retries=2 CMD \
    [[ "$(curl -o /dev/null -s -w "%{http_code}\n" http://localhost:8080/api/health)" == "200" ]]
```

See documentation [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#healthcheck)